# C++ std::set invalid read on insert

Tags: c++, set, containers, std, valgrind

I am writing a server in C++. I use a std::set container to save a pointer which access to all of the client memory object. I use valgrind to check if I don't make any memory leaks. I have a invalid read when I use my set for the first time. I write a little example of code to explain my problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  set<int> s;

  s.insert(1);
  s.insert(2);
  s.insert(3);

  for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++) {
    cout << "Data:" << *it << endl;
    s.erase(it);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I compile with those flags and launch my program with valgrind.

```
g++ -ggdb -std=c++17 set.cpp && valgrind ./a.out'
```

This code produce a "Invalid read of size 8" into std::_Rb_tree_increment(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)

That's not come from my code so I can resolve this problem ?

Sorry for my English, I am learning it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`it` is invalid after you erased it, but [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) returns an iterator following the last erased element, thus you can change the loop to

```
for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end();) {
    cout << "Data:" << *it << endl;
    it = s.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: Thank, I was thinking the problem was form the insert method or many thread tried to access to the set in same time... I just add a mutex to lock the element when I change it and my server work perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Once you call `s.erase(it)`, the iterator `it` is no longer valid. Any reference to the iterator, such as in `it++`, is undefined behavior.

It looks like incrementing `it` in the call of `it++` calls `std::_Rb_tree_increment`, which is in an invalid state at this point. Valgrind detects this condition, and reports an invalid read.

Comment: but it returns an iterator to the next element, so it could be fixed by using that and doing `it++`  only when nothing was erased